# timed_mutex won't compile under Cygwin 4.8.2 ('timed_mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type)

Tags: multithreading, gcc, c++11, cygwin, mutex

My file `test8.cpp` is

```
#include<thread>
#include<mutex>
#include<chrono>

std::mutex mutex;
std::timed_mutex timed_mutex;
```

When I compile this code

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread -c test8.cpp
```

it tells me

> timed_mutex in namespace 'std' does not name a type

I compile under Cygwin64, gcc version 4.8.2

[image: screenshot]

==================================================================

@Jonathan Wakely

[image]

Comment: does [not reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d5fcc9255020a66).

Comment: @SamMiller: does stacked-crooked run on Cygwin though?

Answer (score 2):

The `timed_mutex` type is only defined if the platform supports it. The preprocessor conditions in GCC's `<mutex>` are:

```
#ifdef _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDINT_TR1
```

which is defined if the platform defines a usable `<stdint.h>` header, and

```
#if _GTHREAD_USE_MUTEX_TIMEDLOCK
```

which is defined if the macro `_POSIX_TIMEOUTS` is defined to a positive value by the `<unistd.h>` header.

If the first macro was not defined then you would not be able to use `std::mutex` either, so it seems that only the second macro is undefined, implying that Cygwin's Pthreads implementation doesn't support the Timeouts features.

The test used to check for the Timeouts feature is similar to:

```
#include <unistd.h>
// In case of POSIX threads check _POSIX_TIMEOUTS.
#if (defined(_PTHREADS) \
    && (!defined(_POSIX_TIMEOUTS) || _POSIX_TIMEOUTS <= 0))
#error
#endif
int main() { }
```

You could try compiling that on Cygwin, and checking for the macro yourself. If Cygwin does support the Timeouts features then please [report a GCC bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/) so we can make `timed_mutex` work on Cygwin.

**Edit:** For GCC 6 I have added an [alternative implementation of `std::timed_mutex`](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2015-09/msg00024.html) for platforms that don't define _POSIX_TIMEOUTS. I don't know if that will help on Cygwin or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Jonathan. I don't quite understand these macros. I tried to compile your example, it seems to work. I updated the post, where you can see the screenshot of compilation.

Comment: Huh. Strange. I'm not sure why `timed_mutex` isn't defined then